# Is this a legit way to swap endianness?

Tags: c#, .net

As the title says, I have UInt16 that is read using `BinaryReader` from a file. The file contains hex in order "0x0102" whereas after reading it is in reverse. Is this legit? I heard that BitConverter works according to how the endianness is set in the pc, but I use it twice, so it seems like everything should work fine?

```
public static UInt16 EndiannessSwap(UInt16 data)
{
   var step1 = BitConverter.GetBytes(data);
   var step2 = step1.Reverse().ToArray();
   var step3 = BitConverter.ToUInt16(step2, 0);
   return step3;
}
```

Comment: Have you tested it? If it works then it's legit!

Comment: @SteveJ Please read the concern in the question. This is a legitimate concern that you are ignoring.

Comment: It works for my simple case on my pc, as stated in my question, I'm more concerned with any unforeseen consequences that using BitConverter may bring.

Comment: That doesn't even compile for me - Reverse() returns void.

Comment: If you know the order of the significant bits in the file (that is, it doesn't depend on the host endianness), then use that. `0x01 << 8 | 0x02` (or `0x02 << 8 | 0x01`, if the endianness is the other way) will yield the correct value regardless of how the bits end up in memory. Reading it "wrong" first and then correcting it is inefficient.

Comment: @SteveJ You're missing a using directive then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this code will work and will be portable, although not very efficient.
You are right that `BitConverter` works according to the endianness of the machine, but because you're using it's output as input this cancels out.

A more efficient way of swapping endianness would be using bit shifts. Seeing as an `UInt16` only consists of 2x `byte` (8-bits) we can easily swap it as follows:

```
public static UInt16 EndiannessSwap(UInt16 data)
{
   return unchecked((ushort)((data << 8) | (data >> 8)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using a very similar solution without problems:

```
public static UInt16 EndiannessSwap(UInt16 data)
{
    var intAsBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(data);
    Array.Reverse(intAsBytes);
    return BitConverter.ToUInt16(intAsBytes, 0);
}
```